# How do I prove this simple result for the face structure of convex sets?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, polytopes, convex-geometry

I have a convex set $P$ with faces $f_1, f_2$ such that all extremal points of the convex set belong to either $f_1$ or $f_2$ (the faces are disjoint and cover $P$). How can I prove that if every extremal point of $f_1$ shares an face edge with every extremal point of $f_2$ then $\mathsf{dim}(f_1) + \mathsf{dim}(f_2) < \mathsf{dim}(P)$? Examples include any polygon based pyramid in $d=3$, where $f_1$ is the base and $f_2$ is the vertex at the top of the pyramid (and $0+2 < 3$), or the two edges of a tetrahedron that do not share vertices (but for which every vertex of one shares an edge with every vertex of the other), and $1+1 < 3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not always true. Consider the set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of the points $(1, 0)$, $(0, 1)$, and $(-1, -1)$. Let $f_1 = conv(S \times \{(0, 0)\})$ and $f_2 = conv(\{(0, 0)\} \times S)$. I think this gives a counterexample where each $f_i$ has dimension $2$, but their convex hull has dimension $4$, and any two of the $6$ points share a face edge.